# How to create a dynamic footer

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I went through so many posts since many days but didnt find anything useful. I am developing a website using bootstrap. I have created footer but it does not work correctly on all the pages either it comes in between on one or other page or in some page leaves space on the right. I tried jquery also but no success.

I want to create a footer like the one on stackoverflow which always stays at bottom on all the pages and we can see it when we scroll till last. I have footer on main master page and the rest pages are child master and child pages.

```
 <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container text-right">
            <div id="socialMedia">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

.css

```
 html {
 height: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 *,
 *:before,
 *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
  }

  body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom:-50px;
     }

   .footer {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom:0;
   left: 0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:#333;
   width:100%;
   height:50px;
   margin-bottom:0px;

}
```

Comment: Don't know exactly what do you want...I just created jsfiddle with your above code...it is working....https://jsfiddle.net/3knc2wcg/

Comment: do you have two column layout in main container div ?

Comment: ya the code is working but the footer stays fixed when we resize ... I want a footer like on the stackoverflow not a fixed bottom but we can only see it on the bottom when we scroll till down

Comment: No I have not yet decided the column layout on the main container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply not make the footer absolute, but relative like this:

```
.bodyContent {
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}

.footer {
   position: relative;
   background-color:#333;
   width:100%;
   height:50px;
   margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

[Here your code plus the fix on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0deb5pb5/)

Comment: This works very well ... But the only problem is on another page I have vertical navbar and I want the footer to go above it but it goes behind .. http://snag.gy/Ipjrk.jpg

Comment: @Ashwini Without see your navbar code I can't help you more. If you can add the navbar to my JSFiddle I can try to help you on the real situation. The navbar is a plugin ? or other who can I explore and test ?

Comment: @Ashwini I found it and change it, I hope this can help you: https://jsfiddle.net/0deb5pb5/3/

Comment: Thanks I will try this.. one more thing I increased footer size but it leaves a blank space below.. I tried changing padding but does not work

Comment: Can depend from more possible thing. The content of the page is less of the height of page, the footer or his container have padding or margin. In my example too you can show a blank space below, but if you click on "show more" link, the content fill the page... I can't resolve it now, but I move up the link for test the problem here : https://jsfiddle.net/0deb5pb5/4/

Answer (score 1):

Found the snippets [here](http://bootstrapfooter.codeplex.com/) works really well for bootstrap

Html:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="main" class="container clear-top">
    <p>Your content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
  overflow:auto;
  padding-bottom:150px; /* this needs to be bigger than footer height*/
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 150px;
  clear:both;
  padding-top:20px;
}
```

Source: [Demo](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) and [Tutorial](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

Comment: I tried all the above codes but the problem is I have another page which has a vertical navbar. I want the footer above it but the footer goes behind navbar see this:   [link]http://snag.gy/Ipjrk.jpg

Comment: harshad, thanks but I dont want that type of fixed bottom footer with scrollable content.